# Cakephp persistant line in output

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the code below in a php form that I created. I cannot figure out how to make it so that the output file has the PartColor: line even if nothing is selected from shoe_sizes or color_value.

Currently it adds all the size lines to the output file even if there is no data but the PartColor: line isn't being added when no choice is made.

```
            foreach ($data['Saleslead']['style_numbers'] as $key => $value) {
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "---- Start Product ----\n"; 
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "\n";

                $color_value = $data['Saleslead']['colors'][$key];
                $shoe_sizes = $data['Saleslead']['shoe_sizes'][$key];
                $part_number = $style_number_complete_list[$data['Saleslead']['style_number_id'][$key]]['name'];
                $color_range = $style_number_complete_list[$data['Saleslead']['style_number_id'][$key]]['color_range'];
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "PartNumber: ".$part_number."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "PartColorRange: ".$color_range."\n";  

                if($shoe_sizes != "" || $color_value != ""){
                    $texttoshow = "";
                    if($shoe_sizes != "" && $color_value != ""){
                        $texttoshow = $shoe_sizes;
                    }else if ($shoe_sizes != "" && $color_value == ""){
                        $texttoshow = $shoe_sizes;
                    }else if ($shoe_sizes == "" && $color_value != ""){
                        $texttoshow = $color_value;
                    }
                    $comma_delmited_list .=   "PartColor: ".$texttoshow."\n";  
                }

                $comma_delmited_list .=   "cur_UnitPriceUserEntered: ".$data['Saleslead']['unit_price'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "OrderInstructions: ".$data['Saleslead']['order_instruction'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "Size01_Req: ".$data['Saleslead']['small'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "Size02_Req: ".$data['Saleslead']['medium'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "Size03_Req: ".$data['Saleslead']['large'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "Size04_Req: ".$data['Saleslead']['xlarge'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "Size05_Req: ".$data['Saleslead']['2xlarge'][$key]."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "Size06_Req: ".(isset($data['Saleslead']['other'][$key])?$data['Saleslead']['other'][$key]:"")."\n";  
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "\n";
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "---- End Product ----\n"; 
                $comma_delmited_list .=   "\n";
```

Here is what text looks like after the form is submitted.

PartNumber: 00021

PartColorRange: Darks

cur_UnitPriceUserEntered: 21

OrderInstructions:

Size01_Req: 21

Size02_Req:

Size03_Req:

Size04_Req:

Size05_Req:

Size06_Req:

And I need PartColor: beneath PartColorRange:

Thanks for all the help!

UPDATE* Answer by bill below.

```
                if($shoe_sizes != "" || $color_value != ""){
                    $texttoshow = "";
                    if($shoe_sizes != "" && $color_value != ""){
                        $texttoshow = $shoe_sizes;
                    }else if ($shoe_sizes != "" && $color_value == ""){
                        $texttoshow = $shoe_sizes;
                    }else if ($shoe_sizes == "" && $color_value != ""){
                        $texttoshow = $color_value;
                    }   
                    $comma_delmited_list .=   "PartColor: ".$texttoshow."\n";
                } else {
                    $comma_delmited_list .= "PartColor: \n";    
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are only adding the `PartColor:` string if `$shoe_sizes` or `$color_value` aren't empty.  You could add an `else` block after checking if they are empty if you want `PartColor:` to show regardless.

```
if($shoe_sizes != "" || $color_value != "") {
    // your code
} else {
     $comma_delmited_list .= "PartColor: \n";
}
```

Comment: I added the lines in the spot above (See UPDATE* in the original post) and it isn't being added. Did i just place the code incorrectly? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: I was misplacing it. That line fixed it for me. Thanks!!